# Is this if statement?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter.

I set `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE` in a config file.

Then I find this code in `system/core/Input.php`:

```
$this->_enable_xss= (config_item('global_xss_filtering') === TRUE);
```

What actually this code it doing? It doesn't look like a ternary statement. It seems to me is

```
$this->_enable_xss= (FALSE === TRUE);
```

In this case `$this->_enable_xss` returns FALSE?

Comment: is there more code around the statement?  I would say your assessment is valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expands out to:

```
// If global_xss_filtering is a boolean TRUE (by strict comparison)
if (config_item('global_xss_filtering') === TRUE) {
  // Set _enable_xss to TRUE
  $this->_enable_xss = TRUE;
}
// Otherwise set it FALSE
else $this->_enable_xss = FALSE;
```

The part in `()` `(config_item('global_xss_filtering') === TRUE)` is a boolean comparison which will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  That value is stored in `$this->_enable_xss`.

So in your case, you are correct that you're evaluating

```
$this->_enable_xss= (FALSE === TRUE);
```

... which sets `$this->_enable_xss` to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

each comparison operator returns a boolean. 
Yours checks if you got true left and right.
So, yes, `var_dump(true === false);//bool(false)`

Answer (score 0):

is there more code around the statement?  I would say your assessment is valid.  Looking at this forum http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/160281/#771216 it looks like it's just setting the `_enable_xss` based on the config value so you can control the setting.  Why they need to do a comparison is beyond me, seems unnecessary.